# Makefile variable assignment: 'include' not allowed as variable?

Tags: variables, include, makefile

On my Fedora15 box, I can write Makefiles like this:

```
app  = MyApplication
deps = `pkg-config ...`
```

which works perfectly fine. However, whenever I tried executing such Makefiles on Debian machines, I got errors apparently because of the whitespace around '='. So rewriting them like this:

```
app=MyApplication
deps=`pkg-config ...`
```

fixes it. Now my question is, how is this incompatibility caused? My Fedora make is version 3.82, whereas my Debian one is 3.81. Searching the Changelog of make didn't reveal any changed which would make this possible either..

**EDIT:**

I seem to have found the cause for this weird behavior: In most of my makefiles, I usually use the variable "include" to hold all the pkg-config outputs. Now apparently 'include' is some sort of keyword, which, when **not** used like this on Debian

```
include="stuff"
```

triggers a macro, looking for a path or something. If I use it as shown above, I can use it as a normal variable. But now the interesting part is: I can **always** use 'include' as a variable name on Fedora! Therefore lines like this:

```
include = `pkg-config --blah`
```

worked perfectly under Fedora, but always failed under Debian spitting out lines of "Makefile:2: =: No such file or directory" (it was expetcing the '=' and everything else to be paths apparently)

Now my question still stands however why I can do such things on Fedora (why the 'include macro doesn't seem defined there) but not on Debian?

Comment: I'm running Debian (with make version 3.81-8.2) and I have no problems with spaces around variables.

Comment: @Nicolás Well, I tried this on two Debian machines, one at work and the other one a RaspberryPi, and it always malfunctioned..

Comment: Weird. The documentation explicit states that the whitespaces are supposed to be ignored, see [Setting Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html#Setting). On Linux, `make` uses the macro `isblank()` to detect those whitespaces, which on its turn uses locale settings. Your locale should define a blank as a `<space>` or a `<tab>`. Maybe something is wrong with your locale? What errors do you get?

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek Sorry, if I had used the same variable names in the example as I do in my Makefiles, you would have probably caught the error easier.. check out my question, I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my question still stands however why I can do such things on
>   Fedora (why the 'include macro doesn't seem defined there) but not on
>   Debian?

The different behavior is not caused by the difference in distributions of Linux, but by the difference in the `make` versions in those distribution. If you have whitespace(s) after `include`, before `=` (or any other assignment flavor), `3.81` will incorrectly parse it as an `include` directive.

The same holds for other directives, like for example `vpath`. In `3.81`, assigning a value to a variable named `vpath` does not work if you have a space before the `=`, the variable `vpath` will not be defined. In `3.82`, that was fixed -- if you want to call it that way :-) I would prefer `make` to complain about these variable names in any case.